# Web API redirect not working

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, saml-2.0, adfs, component-space

I'm trying to implement a project using SAML and SP-initiated SSO.  My project is using MS Web API.

The following is the code in my controller which initiates the SAML handshake using CompenentSpace as the SAML Library:

```
   public IHttpActionResult SAMLInitiateRequestToIdp(string DistrictToken)
        {
            _idsRepository.SsoLogEntry( ServerAddress, "SAML/ADFS", null, null, null, 0, "Student", "Info Only", SAMLConfiguration.Current.PartnerIdentityProviderConfigurations + " "/* + Response.ToString()*/, null, null, null);
            string partnerIdP = "simon";
            try
            {
                MapDistrictClaim = false;
                DistrictClaim = DistrictToken;


                partnerIdP = _samlHelper.initiateRequestToSp(DistrictClaim, ServerAddress);

                SAMLServiceProvider.InitiateSSO(System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Response, null, partnerIdP);
                return Ok(new { data = "get ok" });


            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {

                return Ok(new { data = "get ok" });

            }
        }
```

Don't worry about the "catch" clause.  I know it doesn't do anything.

**The issue that I'm running into is that I get the following response when I call this method:**

```
<html><head><title>Object moved</title></head><body>
<h2>Object moved to <a href="https://adfstest.mywebsite.com/adfs/ls/idpinitiatedsignon?SAMLRequest=AAAfZLLbtswEEV%2FReBe1tsPwjLgSDFqIG2FyOmim4IixzYBiVQ5lNsC%2BfhQctKmC2c7jzv3zMwaWdf2dDvYs3qEnwOg9fZlTn6INFs0i0Xjz8MF%2BGlzjPxlkzB%2FnsJKLJciTpuIeN%2FAoNQqJ%2FEsJN4ecYC9QsuUdaEwyvxw5UfJIU5oGNM4ma3C5DvxSjdFKmanzrO1PdIgYOKI1iVmnBkAw80gUarTjOtuygUtBlL0UkkrmQWB8qS0It5OGw6T%2F5wcWYsw%2BqgYorzA30hltNVct3dSCSeak8EoqhlKpIp1gNRyWm8%2FP1DHQZtrEdJPh0PlV1%2FrA%2FG2iGBGw4VWOHRgajAXyeHp8eEfAqK%2BRXCJg1H%2Flszk8CIFmC%2FOTk6ieRY%2Fh2mYbLO0cDsvMz8tw3t%2FWawiv5jv7nb3izTLVvFzzZRXSjhp70nJowTh1fysdeuCaI3klni%2Fu1YhnQ79MXj%2FuiWyWY%2FVdLqnedf%2FcTt7gyObsazgtWt5BXzD24t%2BHbwTv07q6Yi9LyvdSv5nPGnH7O1h0SyaIlL4x6mUDgp74BO%2Fu1Xb6l%2BFAfclObFmcNsNNtep%2F3%2F65gU%3D&amp;SigAlg=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F2000%2F09%2Fxmldsig%23rsa-sha1&amp;Signature=Dv9lr04SrKwRPxKs%2FLpqAqDsWPMcS%2BIFy%2FsLLWcAivf8s6WiV4dvei5LBa4MnYy4hXAyVYJ0JM7L6pBXaPCdz%2Fb5UtF525%2FQi%2Bpv8alyaplWJbXfgXWvjuRY%2FTxpnNN0wVGk7f6ZkCAmDEeZcSNNwW2YJGBvTk5kUORvQq1VhsMhZZmf3Q0VDRdjrTSzQ9K%2BbVEptm9Ed86Jb5I%2BYutc1U43FvSIQTNkpm8phC%2F3BlfyhbDRdMn3sSmCNkyel86oXfl7pnnozpDqPFWc6SRWaWJ%2BMv1IWs2SzcHbfvRAnkTdxx3Gokp%2Fd74f77oJLkUYNKgqsFIhrc6qSNqjO29heA%3D%3D">here</a>.</h2>
</body></html>
{"data":"get ok"}
```

When I emailed Component Space about my initial issue, the response I got back was:  "When you call SAMLServiceProvider.InitiateSSO you are sending a SAML authn request using the HTTP-Redirect binding.

What this means is that a 302 redirect is returned to the browser. For example, see below.

The browser should then perform a GET to this URL which includes the encoded SAMLRequest."

**Is there a reason that I'm getting this response instead of the browser redirecting?**

Answer (score 3):

The answer is that I returned OK, when I should have returned a redirect with the appropriate URL:

```
SAMLServiceProvider.InitiateSSO(System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Response, null, partnerIdP);
return Redirect(System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Response.RedirectLocation);
```